Response 403 in Heroku using GET request in Python
I am trying to get the results from API https://lsc.fn.sportradar.com/betradar/en/Europe:Berlin/gismo/event_fullfeed. It is the GET request; normally opening this URL on browser is working without any authorisation key.
I have also implemented the code and locally it is working fine for me but, after deploying code to Heroku I am start getting <Response [403]>. I have tried every solution but it's not working for me.
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Origin': 'https://ls.betradar.com/',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
            'Referer': 'https://ls.betradar.com/',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
req = requests.get(self.url, headers=headers, timeout=10)

I know similar type of the questions were asked in stackoverflow earlier but, I tried all solutions and none of them worked for me.
If someone faced the similar type of the problem in Heroku. Please let me know if this is the problem with Heroku or something else.
Thanks in advance!

I have also tried using changing the regions of Heroku app but, still getting same error.
